# Eclipse only returning class objects and not the source

Tags: eclipse, search

Using the same version of Eclipse for a while now and have not installed any plugins within the past few months.

The one feature frequently used is right clicking a Java procedure, selecting References from the pop-up menu then Project.

This would return all the associated Java source files from which the specific procedure is being called. This allows me to view the associated source.

For some reason, starting yesterday, when following the same steps, the items returned are the Java class files and not the Java source files. 
When clicking the associated file, I no longer view the source but rather the outline or class information.

I have since closed and restarted Eclipse without any success. 
I also have a 2nd Eclipse window opened with a different project and this one continues to operate as expected.

Some setting much have changed related to this one project but unable to pinpoint what. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The following resolved the above issue.

Posting as potential solution as there doesn't seem to be one specific fix.

Close Eclipse.

Navigate to :
C:\Eclipse\Workspaces\.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core

Delete all files.

Open the project and on the next search the Indexes are rebuilt and it worked.